# CTE query to root element postgres

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

This is a very general question. I found some questions and discussions on more specific problems on SO, but I am quite sure, that many of you have already solved this one:

input:

1. A table that has a tree structure in one field.
2. An arbitrary id of a database record `x`.

question:

How can I get the root of the tree of `x`?

I found out that there should be a way to implement this recursively, but I couldn't achieve it yet.

Comment: There are good cte examples in the docs. Have you tried using them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The root element can be found in the same way as child elements of a given root,
but the query must search in the opposite direction.
Take a look at simple demo: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fdc8a/1

This query retrieves all childrens of a given root:

```
WITH RECURSIVE childs( id, parent_id ) 
AS (
  -- get parent
  SELECT id, parent_id
  FROM tab
  WHERE id = 10

  UNION ALL

  -- get all children
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
  FROM childs c
  JOIN tab t
  ON t.parent_id = c.id
)
SELECT * from childs;
```

and this query retrieves all parents of a given child node:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents( id, parent_id ) 
AS (
  -- get leaf children
  SELECT id, parent_id
  FROM tab
  WHERE id = 14

  UNION ALL

  -- get all parents  
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
  FROM parents p
  JOIN tab t
  ON p.parent_id = t.id
)
SELECT * from parents
-- WHERE parent_id is null;
```

if only the root node is needed, a clause `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` filters out all except the root.